# Split data into a new line in oracle but in the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, newline

I have Data like this

ColumnA ColumnB CloumnC

1       king    Dog,cat

I want show the data like as shown below in only one row "cat" should be shown in new line in the same row

ColumnA ColumnB CloumnC

1       king    Dog
                Cat
                 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the split-character "," with a linefeed character.

```
WITH sample_data
AS ( select null      as ColumnA
     ,      'King'    as ColumnB
     ,      'Dog,Cat' as ColumnC
     FROM   dual
   )
SELECT ColumnA
,      ColumnB
,      REPLACE(ColumnC,',',CHR(10))
FROM   sample_data
```

Answer (score 0):

A **new line** depends on the **Operating system**. In **Unix** based OS, it is `CHR(10)`, in **Windows** it is `CHR(13)` **followed by** `CHR(10)`.

In Windows OS:

```
SELECT columna
,      columnb
,      REPLACE(columnc,',',CHR(10)||CHR(13))
FROM   table;
```

In Unix based OS:

```
SELECT columna
,      columnb
,      REPLACE(columnc,',',CHR(10))
FROM   table;
```